# Solve these systems of equations

Tags: analysis, exponential-function, systems-of-equations

Consider the two equations below:

$$
y_{1}=\left(1-\frac{a_{1}}{x}\right)e^{-\dfrac{\alpha\, a_{1}}{x}}\\
y_{2}=\left(1-\frac{a_{2}}{x}\right)e^{-\dfrac{\alpha\, a_{2}}{x}}
$$

Given $y_{1}$, $y_{2}$, $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$, is there an analytical way to determine $\alpha$ and $x$? I tried several approaches. Any suggestions or comments will be appreciated

Comment: Define "analytical"

Comment: @Ethan I mean without resort to a numerical method, explicit or implicit expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using the parameters you gave. I rewrote user44197 approach reducing to same denominator, removing the common denominator. This made the equation better condioned.

A plot of the function reveals a solution close to x=0.01 and the solution, obtained using Newton, is x=0.0133409. From here, alpha=1.584997.

I also used the solution based on the Lambert function. Here again, the plot of the fuction reveal a root close to alpha=1.5. Starting from here, Newton iterations lead again to alpha=1.584997. Frm here, x=0.0133409.

Then, again, both approaches work and lead to the same results.

Please post where are your problems. As told earlier, the problem is a resonable starting guess for the solution; this can be easily obtained looking at the plot of the function.

Comment: @Dear Claude Leibovici, I can't thank you enough. I just coded my solution and it works. I think the original equation was very ill conditioned leading to non-sense results. With your suggestions and a reasonable guess from the plot, I am getting very nice values and for the case I posted, they agree with your result:) Thanks once again and I wish you were my mentor. I am a beginner researcher in the field of numerical analysis

Comment: @felasfa. If you like my answer, may be you could accept it in order new users know that this is a valid approach. I am glad to have been able to help. If you need more about numerical analysis, just contact me; it is my favoured area. Cheers.

Comment: @Dear Claude Leibovici, I did accept your answer. Thank you once again. I guess I am kind of new to the area of numerical analysis. I do have a strong background in theoretical PDE and analysis. What do you recommend as classics/must to read for a beginner? Aside from that, what skills(programming or other) should one develop? If it is kind of tangent, we may discuss this over email if you will. thanks

Comment: @felasfa. You can contact me at any time using my e-mail which is cfl-consultant@club-internet.fr. You will always be welcome. Start the discussion.

Comment: #Dear Claude Leibovici, did now didn't know the difference between up vote and accept, I do now :) Thanks for your email, I will email you shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\frac{y_1^{a_2}}{y_2^{a_1}} = \frac{\left(1-\frac{a_{1}}{x}\right)^{a_2}}
{\left(1-\frac{a_{2}}{x}\right)^{a_1}}$$
This eliminates $\alpha$.

Not sure how you can solve this *analytically*. But once you get $x$ , you can solve for $\alpha$ by taking logarithm of either equation.

Comment: thank you. I guess I have to use some sort of numerical method on the above equation.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that analytical methods would allow to solve this problem. But, considering your equations, there are a few things which can be done at least to reduce the problem to a single equation in "alpha" (user44197 already proposed a way to solve first for x).

Just multiply the lhs and rhs by Exp[alpha]. We then have

y1 Exp[alpha] = (1 - a1 / x) Exp[alpha (1 - a1 / x)]
y2 Exp[alpha] = (1 - a2 / x) Exp[alpha (1 - a2 / x)]

Now, introduce z1 = (1 - a1 / x) and z2 = (1 - a2 / x). So, the previous equations write

y1 Exp[alpha] = z1 Exp[alpha z1]
y2 Exp[alpha] = z2 Exp[alpha z2]

So, we have

z1 = W(t1) / alpha
z2 = W(t2) / alpha

W(t) representing Lambert function with arguments

t1 = alpha y1 Exp[alpha]
t2 = alpha y2 Exp[alpha]

Back to x, we then have

x = alpha a1 / (alpha - W(t1)) = alpha a2 / (alpha - W(t2))

So, we need to solve one equation for "alpha" and this equation can write

a1 (alpha - W(t2)) = a2 (alpha - W(t1))

When the solution of this equation in "alpha" has been solved, the value of "x" is directly obtained. It must be noticed that this equation has an obvious solution for alpha=0 which needs to be discarded.

For illustration purposes, I used a1=2, a2=3, y1=1/2, y2=-1/4. The solution corresponds to
alpha = -0.852141 and x = 2.73205

Comment: How do I solve the equation in alpha since t1 and t2 themselves are also functions of alpha?

Comment: @felasfa. Precisely, replace t1 and t2 by their expressions. You then have a single equation where only alpha appears. Depending on your level and software capabilities, the solution I propose may not be the easiest way to solve but it works nice. Otherwise, use the solution proposed by user44197; it involves simpler functions. Both answers show that you can eliminate one variable and stay with one equation for one unknown. Please tell me if I can do more for you with this problem. Cheers.

Comment: @Dear Claude Leibovici, thank you for the reply. I do have a decent numerical background, what solution do you propose?I am thinking of optimization/root solving but may not be clean implementations.

Comment: @felasfa. You have been given two ways for reducing the problem to one single equation and I think this is the way to go. If you do not have a CAS for using my way based on Lambert function, the simplest method would be the one suggested by user44197. Use Newton method starting with a "good" guess of the solution. Tell me if you want I make an example for you; if so, provide me a set of parameters of your choice. I shall post the results later here. Cheers.

Comment: @Dear Claude Leibovici, thank you for your reply. I tried implementing Newton's method with user44197 method. With parameters $a_{1}=2.896*10^-3$, $a_{2}=6.981*10^{-3}$,$y_{1}=0.555$ and $y_{2}=0.208$, I don't get reasonable values, by reasonable I mean sth that makes sense. My guess for $x$ is $a_{2}+1e-6$. I have a CAS on my laptop(Matlab, Mathematics, Maple..) and also I am familiar with coding and SciPy. How did you go about solving the single equation in alpha for your case? Thank you once again.

Comment: @felasfa. Please see my new answer below based on the coefficient values you provided.